# Why isn't my UIViewController responding to touches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a UIViewController that contains a UIScrollView, which has a UIView inside of its contentview.

I have the following code that does not work, keyboard is not dismissed, why?:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Touch Events
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == scrollView || [touch view] == self.view)
    {
        [usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the textfield delegate to self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touchesBegan:withEvent:` is a `UIView` method, not a `UIViewController` method. What are you trying to achieve here? You should very seldom have a UI reaction to `touchesBegan:`. You probably mean to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead.

Make sure to use accessors (`self.scrollView`) rather than accessing your ivars directly. Direct ivar access is the #1 cause of memory management crashes.

Comment: Also, note that like `touchedBegan:withEvent:`, `UITapGestureRecognizer`s are added to the `UIView`, not the `UIViewController`. Though they can and should send actions to the controller.

Comment: UIViewController IS a subclass of UIResponder so it can catch input events!